# python great expectation compatible with pyspark

Tags: python, data-quality, great-expectations

I am implementing data quality checks using Great expectation library. does this library compatible with Pyspark does this run on multiple cores?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is compatible with Pyspark. Here is the example.

datasource creation.

```
datasources:
  spark_ds:
    class_name: Datasource
    execution_engine:
      module_name: great_expectations.execution_engine
      class_name: SparkDFExecutionEngine
      force_reuse_spark_context: true
    module_name: great_expectations.datasource
    data_connectors:
      spark_ds_connector:
        class_name: RuntimeDataConnector
        module_name: great_expectations.datasource.data_connector
        batch_identifiers:
          - batch_id
```

Create runtime batch request

```
df=#Create your dataframe
request=RuntimeBatchRequest(
            datasource_name="spark_ds",
            data_connector_name="spark_ds_connector",
            data_asset_name="any_asset_name",  

            runtime_parameters={"batch_data": df},  

            batch_identifiers={"batch_id": "batch_id"},
        )
    
    
ge_context.run_checkpoint(checkpoint_name="checkpoint", validations=[{"batch_request": request, "expectation_suite_name": "suite_name"}])
```

Comment: I have simply created in this format ```gedf = ge.dataset.SparkDFDataset(df1)
DQI=gedf.expect_column_values_to_be_unique("ID", result_format = "COMPLETE")```  to remove unnecessary overhead. But failing with Python kernel unresponsive. not sure this error because of OOM.

Comment: Should be OOM, because as per the documentation ( and also code) the results are collected to the driver memory. So only one node does the job.